# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError appears after SherlockActionBar was added

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I added SherlockActionBar (layouts were not changed since prev version), tested my app in several devices and everything worked fine but ACRA has been reporting about new and new similar errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.aviascanner.aviascanner/net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.SearchResultsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:418)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:178)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
        ... 28 more
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:418)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:178)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
        ... 28 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:418)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:178)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
        ... 28 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:418)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:178)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
        at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3371)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[My question in SherlockActionBar issues tracker](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/852)

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Look at hprof dumps and see what memory is being leaked, or what memory being used you can do without?

Comment: Does it means I must reproduce the bug? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: You can try doing this on a phone where it doesn't crash, its likely that there's only a problem on low RAM phones and you can see memory use increasing even on working ones, they just have enough memory to handle it.

Comment: But how it is possible if it worked pretty good in prev version (without fragments and actionbar)? I didn't change any layouts - just ported activities and dialogs.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you changed.  But my guess is that either the actionbar is holding onto references that are then not cleanable by the gc, or that the fragments are.

Comment: Ok, so I should dig into memory usage. But I never done it before. Will the article help me (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)?

Comment: THat's a good reference.  There's also was a talk about memory use a year or two ago at Google IO

Answer (score 0):

The OutofMemory Exception comes because of the drawables available in the res folders. The drawables should be available in aa the folders of drawable not in a single folder to avoid the OutofmemoryException.

Comment: how about http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch ??
and I hadn't this error in the prev version

Comment: you can check the effect on heap size by the DDMS after changes the drawables. If the drawable not found in the folder relating to the device resolution then the device has to change according to the resolution and the heap size grows rapidly and it throws the **OutOfMemoryException**.